# MySQL Update records with relations and duplicate values

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with updating data in my database and I can't figure it out if it's even possible.

I have tables:

`products_properties` with columns `prop_new`, `prod_id`,

`product_categories` with columns `prod_id` and `cat_id`,

`categories` with column `cat_id`

Now each product is assigned to one or more categories via table `product_categories` and there are about 200 products with `prop_news` set to '1' in each category and it's way to many.

I'd like to limit number of products with `prop_news` set to '1' to 12 for each category.

I don't know how to write a query.
If you have any sugestions I'd be more than happy to look at it.

Comment: your query seems incomplete. Kindly elaborate criteria for setting `prop_new`. Explain your requirement precisely.

Comment: @seahawk each product has property `prop_new` with value `0` or `1` to show if this product is new on stock or not. Also each product can be visible in different categories. What I want to achieve is to iterate through each category and for each product in that category set `prop_new` `0` except for 12 products in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can look this as an aproach to solve your problem. This query save only one prod_new with value 1. Change `where n > 1` with count you need

```
drop table if exists t1;
create table t1 (prod_new int, prod_id int);
insert into t1 values 
(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5);

drop table if exists t2;
create table t2 (prod_id int, cat_id int);
insert into t2 values 
(1,1), (2,1), (3,2), (4, 2), (5,2);

update t1 
    set prod_new=0 
  where prod_id in 
    (select prod_id 
         from 
           (select prod_id, @n:=if(@c=cat_id, @n:=@n+1, if(@c:=cat_id, 1, 1)) n 
                from t2 
                       cross join 
                     (select @n:=0,  @c:=0) n  
              order by cat_id 
           ) t 
      where n > 1 
   );

select * from t1
```